# In Ruby, if you assign a function to a variable, why does it automatically run?

Tags: ruby, methods, irb

Using the code below:

```
variable = puts "hello world".upcase
```

Why does Ruby automatically puts Hello world in upcase, without the variable first being invoked? I understand that you are setting the function to the variable, and if that variable is called it will return the return value (in this case, nil), but why is it that Ruby runs the method `puts "hello world".upcase`almost without permission (have not called it, merely assigned to a variable)?

Comment: You are not assigning function to variable. You are assigning return value of function to variable so the function runs first so you get the value for assignment.

Comment: Ruby doesn't have pure first-class functions like Python or JavaScript. In Python, you have to call a function -- `foo` is a reference to the function object `foo`, and `foo()` is a call to that function. In Ruby, `foo` is a call to the function -- other syntax is needed to get a `Method` object.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are not assigning a function to a variable.

This is the same as

```
variable = (puts("hello world".upcase))
```

It needs to execute `puts` to assign the returned value to the variable variable (lol).

This is a way to assign a method to a variable.

```
puts_method = method(:puts)
```

Comment: I've tried to put in method = puts(:hello), but it like the other variable example just runs similarly without permission. Could you provide an example using puts "hello world" where it would store the method within the variable without running it?

Comment: In ruby there are these `callable objects`. Something like `puts_hello_word = lambda { puts "hello world" }`

Comment: and call it with `puts_hello_word.call`

Comment: Ok, I will look into that. Thank you for your time spent answering the question @Ursus.